# OpenCV, pthread - show image within a new thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, image-processing, opencv, pthreads

I have a main function to take image from somewhere, and it should be displayed within a new thread. This is what I'm doing:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat frame = imread("img.jpg");

    auto_ptr<SomeClass> thread1(new SomeClass(1, frame));
    auto_ptr<SomeClass> thread2(new SomeClass(2, frame));

    thread1->Start();
    thread2->Start();

    int result1 = reinterpret_cast<int>(thread1->Join());
    int result2 = reinterpret_cast<int>(thread2->Join());

    return 0;
}
```

I have found many source codes to implement a simple pthread wrapper class, which ones are working well, as long as I don't try to pass the "cv::Mat frame" image to the derived thread (through its constructor).

The pthread wrapper class:

```
/* ********************* THREAD.H ********************* */
extern "C++" class __declspec(dllexport) Thread 
{
public:
    Thread();
    virtual ~Thread(void);

    void Start(void);
    void* Join(void);

private:
    virtual void* Run(void) = 0;

    static void* StartThread(void* pVoid);

    pthread_t threadID_;
    pthread_attr_t threadAttribute_;
    void* result_;
};

/* ********************* THREAD.CPP ********************* */
Thread::Thread() {}

Thread::~Thread() {}

void* Thread::StartThread(void* pVoid) 
{
    Thread* aThread = static_cast<Thread*>(pVoid);
    aThread->result_ = aThread->Run();
    return aThread->result_;
}

void Thread::Start() 
{
    pthread_attr_init(&threadAttribute_);
    pthread_attr_setscope(&threadAttribute_, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);

    pthread_create(&threadID_, &threadAttribute_, Thread::StartThread, (void*)this);
    pthread_attr_destroy(&threadAttribute_);
}


void* Thread::Join() 
{
    pthread_join(threadID_, NULL);
    return result_;
}
```

The subclass of Thread can look like below:

```
/* ********************* SOMECLASS.H ********************* */
extern "C++" class __declspec(dllexport) SomeClass : public Thread
{
public:
    SomeClass(int id, cv::Mat& frame);
    ~SomeClass(void);

    virtual void* Run();
private:
    int id_;
    cv::Mat frame_;
};

/* ********************* SOMECLASS.CPP ********************* */
SomeClass::SomeClass(int id, cv::Mat& frame) : id_(id)
{
    frame_ = frame.clone();
}

SomeClass::~SomeClass(void) {}

void* SomeClass::Run() 
{
    cout << id_ << ", " << frame_.cols << ", " << frame_.rows << endl;

    imshow("frame " + id_, frame_);
    waitKey(1);

    return reinterpret_cast<void*>(id_);
}
```

The execution breaks at line imshow()... Any idea that what can cause this problem or how can I solve it?

Comment: do you have a compiler that supports c++11, or access to boost::thread?

Comment: How does it break? Does it work if you do it in a single thread?

Comment: I'm using VS2010, which one doesn't support c++11, and I don't like to use boost.

EDIT:
It brakes with an "Access violation".. Writes the resolution (frame_.cols and frame_.rows) well, then brakes at the line imshow(). It is also working as well in a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. If anybody has a similar trouble, then:
the whole OpenCV project need to be rebuilt with Intel TBB support. (It's working well with OpenCV 2.3.1)